# Do players know if a hit from a monster is a critical hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack, critical-hit

There are a few different abilities that PCs can get where once they are hit with an attack they can decide to use to potentially turn the hit into a miss. Examples include the spell *Shield* or a Cavalier fighter's *Warding Maneuver* feature.

The way our group currently plays all the DM's rolls are hidden from us and they convey whether attacks hits or misses to us. In the case of a hit the player informally has until the DM rolls damage to decide whether to use a feature that might change the outcome.

**While the players are aware of when an attack is a hit, are they aware if the attack is a critical hit?** If so they would know that using such features would be a waste of resources.

This would also apply to rare features that can force a reroll after an attack roll is already made such as with the Rune Knight's *Runic Shield* feature. If a player knows that an attack is a critical hit they would be more inclined to use such features.

Comment: If reopened, [this question on what rolls should be open](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102063/what-rolls-should-players-get-to-see) is very relevant.

Comment: Related on [How much does a bard know when they decide to use cutting words?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91834/how-much-does-a-bard-know-when-they-decide-to-use-cutting-words)

Comment: Related: [Do reactions that trigger on saving throws give knowledge of saving throws that would otherwise be secret?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177906)

Comment: As far as I can see, the related question ([What rolls should players get to see?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102063/52137)) covers the general, while this is asking about one of the consequences of one of the ways of doing it (which doesn't arise from others). I'll go ahead and clean out a bunch of comments now, if no-one minds.

Comment: For those answering, please note that if there isn't a specific rule around this and you are giving guidance to please back up your subjective answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Yes, they need to know if an attack is a critical hit

Although there are no rules regarding this as far as I know, as rolling in the open or behind a screen is optional, there are abilities in the game that are reliant on knowing if an attack was a critical hit or not.

As one example, the [Grave Domain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#GraveDomain) of the cleric class has the [Sentinel at Death's Door](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#SentinelatDeath%E2%80%99sDoor-669) feature (XGtE, p. 20):

> At 6th level, you gain the ability to impede death’s progress. As a reaction when you or an ally that you can see within 30 feet of you suffers a critical hit, you can turn that attack into a normal hit. Any effects triggered by a critical hit are canceled.

If the player had no way to tell if an attack was a critical hit, this feature would be worthless.

From a DM point of view, I would argue that the players should know when an attack is a crit, for a number of reasons. It builds tension and excitement, and it lets them use the abilities that might save them (the Lucky feat or the [Rune Knight fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#RuneKnight)'s [Runic Shield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#RunicShield-2992787) feature (TCoE, p. 45-46)) or not waste the abilities that won't (the [*shield*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield) spell).

Even if rolling in the open, the DM should still state that the hit was critical, as there are monsters and abilities that cause critical hits on values lower than a 20 on the die.

Comment: Related: [Do reactions that trigger on saving throws give knowledge of saving throws that would otherwise be secret?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177906)

Comment: Wouldn't this also strongly tip the hat on rolls for things like Cutting Words? While I agree this is preferable, i'm not sure this is a must have for some tables. And addressings the potential permutations and issues would move this answer into a more positive territory for me.

Comment: Maybe, cutting words needs to be done after the attack roll but before the DM states the success or fail of the roll. And I agree about the optional nature of stating the crits, if no one at the table had an ability that requires knowledge of crits then it isn't required (but can still be fun)

Comment: I still think you need to support this more as there isn't a clear rule here. But this is also why I dislike hidden rolls in general.

Comment: +1 makes good sense and thanks for pointing out the Grave Domain Cleric's ability to turn a crit into a non-crit.

Comment: From a RP perspective, you would think a character notices, for example, if an enemy has stabbed him in the jugular for a critical hit.

Comment: @personjerry Indeed, it’s actually possible for players to infer enemy crits without metagaming because relative damage numbers (but not absolute numbers) can be inferred by the characters themselves just by observing the attacks, and one attack from a given opponent doing a lot more damage is pretty easy to see.

Comment: As a DM, you have to roll a lot, which means you will roll a lot more crits than any individual player. It's more efficient to just say 'the monster crits, heres the damage'. than DM: 'the monster rolls a 24 to hit, which I assume is a hit, here's the damage' Wizard: 'thats a ton of damage, I use a Shield spell to block the attack'  DM: 'it was a crit, so you can't block it with shield, sorry' and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I see no harm in telling them, and if you have a monster that can push a critical hit aside with a special feature you need to know as a DM also.  I have always told my players when a hit is critical and have never worried if they use a power of theirs to stop the hit.  Often everyone; myself included (DM), cheer and are excited that they got to use a rare power to save themselves.